# Importxml price from url-list - different syntax for each source

Tags: html, xml, xpath, import, google-sheets

I am trying to do a price check for a list of products in Google Spreadsheet, the products come from different web-stores and there is more than one syntax/semantics used. If the price is mentioned in a Meta tag the extract goes fine, if in span content or span inline, it works sometimes.

Problem 1: I would like help to fix the span extract codes as they do not always work, even if existing in the html.

Problem 2: When the extract is fixed, I would like to combine all the codes so that if one do not work, the formula will test the next option. Anyone that can help me? And can this be done a way that reduces the time needed to get the prices (as now it takes several hours for a spreadsheet with 250 products.

And it would also be helpful to extract the currency and add it if it is not included already.

The 3 most commonly used html structures I want to extract the price from is:

```
<meta itemprop="price" content="1999">
```

Cell A: `https://www.tanum.no/_hobby-og-fritid/maling-og-tegning/colour-me-good:-cara-delevingne-9780957314870`

Cell B: `=IF(ISURL(A1); IMPORTXML(A1 ;"//meta[@itemprop='price']/@content");"NULL")`

= 119 (code works for all that use "meta" as far as I can tell)

```
<span itemprop="price" content="1999"></span>
```

Cell A: `http://www.adlibris.com/no/bok/banksy-in-new-york-9780990643715`

Cell B: `=IF(ISURL(A1); IMPORTXML(A1 ;"//span[@itemprop='price']/@content");"NULL")`

= #N/A (code works for 1 out of 10 of the URLs with "span" and "content")

```
<span itemprop="price">1999</span>
```

Cell A: `https://www.zalando.no/hagloefs-lava-50-sportsveske-h2744a00f-m11.html`

Cell B: `=IF(ISURL(A1); IMPORTXML(A1 ;"//span[@itemprop='price']");"NULL")`

= 849kr (code works for some of the URLs with "span" and "inline text")

Answer (score 0):

You can actually just add 2 variations of a simplified xpath in there and then using sort and trim to only return the one with a real value in it like this:

```
=trim(sort(IMPORTXML(A1,"//*[@*='price']|//*[@*='price']/@content")))
```

[image]

Also to get the price for your second xpath you can use this:

```
=trim(IMPORTXML(A2,"//*[contains(@itemprop,'price')]/@content"))
```